Perpendicularly project points onto a curved line
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1. I have points (in blue) on several profiles (3) and unfortunately the points aren't at the same location on each different profile. So in order to compare the spatial distribution of my data across these 3 profiles, I would like to project each point on a line (black) I drew manually, so that I could retrieve the red points I drew on the image below. And then calculate distances between each red points and make my 2D graph.
I however do not have the slightest clue about how to go about it. Maybe create lines from the points to the line? And make an intersection? But so far I was only able to find how to create perpendicular lines on points already on a line, not between a line and points...
I tried using the Near tool but it doesn't allow to set the projection to an angle of 90° (and also did some weird stuff to my feature class...).
Any ideas?

Edit: Following this process
https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-create-connection-lines-between-points-and-a-lin-000030465
Here is the result. Connecting lines in red shows they aren't perpendicular to the line at all time


Mathematically, the red dots are closest to each of their blue parents. A simple vanilla nearest-neighbor approach would therefore solve both your problems in one go.

The Near tool or generate near table tool are the tools you want to be using.  What do you mean by "weird stuff", you need to show that. I would look to ensure your line and point data are in the same projected coordinate system as a first step.

@swiss_knight I thought that using the Near tool which is supposed to give the nearest neightbor that could work but somehow surprisingly it doesn't?

@Hornbydd The weird stuff was me forgetting to duplicate my OG layer. Please ignore that. Today I have been following this process https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/how-to-create-connection-lines-between-points-and-a-lin-000030465. I added the result to the post. The connection lines clearly show this isn't a perpendicular projection for some reason?
